# Laptop LCD replacement

Tags: lcd, laptop-repair

Hey I have just replaced the LCD in my HP nx6125 laptop with one out of a Toshiba A60 which is the same resolution etc but I get this weird issue on the right hand side where it repeats a column of pixels and then a big black column.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I could try?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tricky case :-)
Here is the [service manual reference](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/DocumentIndex.jsp?contentType=SupportManual&lang=en&cc=us&prodSeriesId=471753&prodTypeId=321957)
The service manual is listed on that page as,
`HP Compaq nx6115 and nx6125 Notebook PC - Maintenance and Service Guide`

You might want to recheck if the connectivity of your new panel is compatible with the HP model. Resolution match is not sufficient. I hope you confirmed the panel was completely compatible.

Comment: Yeah I have a feeling that it's just not compatible. It's rated to the same resolution etc but I may have to just buy a new one.